# How should default behaviours be defined in user stories

Tags: agile, scrum, behavior

I'm currently busy writing business rules and user stories for a project I'm on. For a few stories there should be default behaviours like the following.

The application handles orders for representatives. When a order is placed for a certain region, it should pick a default warehouse (some regions have their own warehouses).

I'm wondering how you can define these behaviours for user stories. Are these considered business rules?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering how you can define these behaviours for user stories.

They're expectations of the user that you're making explicit.

> Are these considered business rules?

Yes.

The tricky part is this.

- Story 1: The order is handled manually and a user picks the warehouse.  This is front-and-center of everyone's mind.  They talk about this at length.
- Story 2: The order is handled automatically and a warehouse is picked by the system.  This is assumed.  What more important is that there's no actual user interaction here.  It just "happens" without an actor seeing it or interacting with it.  Since there's no interaction, it's not a very good user story.  It doesn't lead to a fancy screen and the normal artifacts that go along with a proper user story where a user has interaction with the system.

When "automatic" or "default" things happen, the user story becomes a kind of degenerate case where it seems like less work needs to be done because there's no screens or pages or forms or interaction.

However, when "automatic" or "default" things happen some user somewhere actually does care and actually does need to see that it did happen.  Even if it happens in bulk.  Somewhere else, there's a variation on user story 2.

- Story 3: Someone, somewhere, checks the counts and totals for the default warehouse assignments, including manual and defaults.  Here, the default warehouse assignment is seen by an actor who is interacting with the system.

Automatic or default behaviors often highlight the need for review or audit or overview stories to be sure the automatic stuff really happened correctly.

Answer (score 2):

'Sounds to me like you just did an excellent job.

And yes - this is very definitely the kind of detail that absolutely BELONGS in a use case.

IMHO...

Comment: Ok, so should this be defined in a user story? Would something like "When an order in Region A is placed, warehouse 1 should be used"?

Comment: I think you had it better the first time ... IMHO

Comment: That is a good user story, your "Region A => Warehouse 1" would be a good acceptance test that validates the story.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the default behavior is the main user stories and any alternative is another user stories.

So Yes  you have to add this user story.

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: There are many different styles.  But it's most common to break use cases/user stories down by *scenario*, then discuss different *alternatives* (including exception cases) within the *same* scenario.  Otherwise you risk losing "context".  Which is the main point of having use cases in the first place.